# XC16 writing to files in MPLAB

Tags: pic, xc16

I'm attempting to write data into a text file in MPLAB X IDE v3.61.
I am using the newest version of the XC16 compiler. The problem I'm having is that when I run the program, the text file 'BUFFER' isn't getting created in my project folder.

```
#include "xc.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <libq.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <libpic30.h>
#include <dsp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{

    FILE * fp; 
    dataFile=fopen("BUFFER.txt","w");
    fprintf(dataFile, "100"); 
     while(1)
    {

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What target are you running this on?  MPLAB is normally used to write code for PIC microcontrollers, which do not inherently have any concept of what a "file" is, much less have any access to a folder on your computer.

Comment: I'm using the pickit 3 debugger. I got the file to show in my project folder by using a better extension: "C:/Users/Owner/MPLABXProjects/Project_00.x/BUFFER.txt". And I attempted to run my dspic33ep controller but you are right. My controller isnt operating (Heartbeat LED stops working) when I add the file I/O code.

Answer (score 0):

You are working on an embedded machine so you cannot access your PC's file system from the PIC firmware. `fopen()` ist good for writing data to an SD Card for example.